# Count Cell Changes

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, logging, rtd

Current script tracks cell changes from cell A1 and counts those changes in cell B1. However it only works when you actively input a number or text and then hit enter in cell A1. I need the formula to work when the A1 cell is referenced from another cell to count the changes.

```
Option Explicit
Private prevVal As String
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
  If Worksheets("Sheet1").ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
  Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Me.Range("A1").Value <> prevVal Then
    Me.Range("B1").Value = Me.Range("B1").Value + 1
    prevVal = Me.Range("A1").Value
    End If
 End If
 Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please try better explaining what "when the A1 cell is referenced from another cell" means? Should we understand that the "A1" cel value is a result of a formula?

Comment: Correct. As an example A1 could reference A6 = "Apple" then when I change A6 to "Orange" it does not count that change because it is a referenced cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the "A1" cell value is the result of a formula, you should use `Calculate` event. Please, copy this code event in the sheet code module:

```
Option Explicit

Private prevVal As String
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   If Me.Range("A1").value <> prevVal Then
        Me.Range("B1").value = Me.Range("B1").value + 1
        prevVal = Me.Range("A1").value
    End If
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI...I had to add ``Application.EnableEvents = False`` and ``Application.EnableEvents = True`` to make it work properly as it was acting funny w/ other scripts I have running.

Comment: Can you help me add a ActiveX toggle button to this script? I am trying to work on it but it interferes w/ the ``Private prevVal As String``

Comment: @mjac I do not understand what you mean... Do you want me adding a toggle button each time the value in "A1" changes? If not, what does "add a ActiveX toggle button to this script" means?

Comment: I edited the original ? to clarify what I am getting at w/ the toggle button. It is a nice to have but the code works good w/out it. Was just trying to control the activation of the script via a toggle button so I can turn on/off.

Comment: I figured it out. Just had my variables in the wrong place. I updated the original ? w/ the correct toggle button syntax and it works. Thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: @mjac If you intended conditioning the event to increment according to the toggle button value, you should ask in a different way... Sorry, I did not understand what you meant and I was not available to see your updated question. But solving it by your own is the best way to remember it and learn.